# Didn't declare abstract class but is saying can instantiate anyways?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm getting the error that won't allow me to instantiate my class within a method, because it says it is abstract. However, I didn't declare the class abstract so I don't know why it would do this. Any suggestions?

```
public class myTemps implements Temperatures {

   public myTemps(String[] array)

      @Override
       public ListOfStrings subList(int fromIndex) {
          if (fromIndex>this.size()){ 
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
          }
          Temperatures sub=new myTemps(10);
        }
     }
```

Comment: _Any suggestions?_ Yeah, post your code.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code and perhaps the stack trace? Otherwise it's impossible to tell.

Comment: you probably have an abstract method inside that class?

Comment: abstract methods can only be defined in abstract classes.

Comment: Show us `ListOfStrings`... and the exact error message.

Comment: You are trying to instanciate `ListOfStrings` not `MyListOfStrings`

Comment: I'm voting to close, downvoting, the whole shebang. Please put some effort into your questions and problems.

Comment: As you can see, bad questions will get you crushed out here. I don't personally have a problem with the actual question but people shouldn't have to coax the question out of you. 

Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to save yourself problems in the future

Comment: Also a recommendation to try to improve the formatting of your code that you post in here and your code in general. Good formatting including using an indentation style that is uniform and consistent will help others (**us**!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, it will help **you** to better understand your code and thus fix your own bugs. Also it shows that you're willing to put in extra effort to make it easier for the volunteers here to help you, and that effort is **much** appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't instantiate an Interface, you need to do

```
new MylistOfStrings(10);
```

Comment: omg sorry I feel so dumb, I've been up for hours working on this and they are names so similarily

Comment: Not a problem, don't feel dumb, the internet is unforgiving. IMHO the question is valid within a certain context, albeit very basic. Not sure what IDE you are using in class but the compiler doesn't lie (most of the time). An IDE can help you in these cases. If you are not using an IDE you should get yourself familiar with eclipse or something and go through the tutorials. Good luck.